# kind get clusters - not working with my local Kind-powered Kubernetes cluster

Tags: podman, kind

)

I'm trying to follow [Working with your Kind cluster | Podman Desktop](https://podman-desktop.io/docs/kubernetes/kind/working-with-your-local-kind-cluster)
yet encounter the following error:

```
% kind get clusters
ERROR: failed to list clusters: command "docker ps -a --filter label=io.x-k8s.kind.cluster --format '{{.Label "io.x-k8s.kind.cluster"}}'" failed with error: exit status 1
Command Output: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/alexus/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
% podman ps -a --filter label=io.x-k8s.kind.cluster --format '{{.Label "io.x-k8s.kind.cluster"}}'
Error: template: ps:1:13: executing "ps" at <.Label>: can't evaluate field Label in type containers.psReporter
% podman --version
podman version 4.7.1
%
```

---

```
% kubectl config current-context
kind-kind
% kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.2", GitCommit:"7f6f68fdabc4df88cfea2dcf9a19b2b830f1e647", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-17T14:20:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.1", GitCommit:"4c9411232e10168d7b050c49a1b59f6df9d7ea4b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-12T19:03:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
% uname -a
Darwin mbp.local 23.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.0.0: Fri Sep 15 14:42:42 PDT 2023; root:xnu-10002.1.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
%
```

Please advise)

Answer (score 0):

after adding an env var: `KIND_EXPERIMENTAL_PROVIDER=podman`, this error gone.

see: https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/rootless/#creating-a-kind-cluster-with-rootless-podman